# model summary output from auto_arima

Tags: time-series, arima

what does [1, 2] mean in SARIMAX(2, 0, 0)x(0, 1, [1, 2], 12) in the model summary output especially the seasonal order printed out to be (0,1,2,12)? This is the model summary output based on the best model produced by auto_arima process in Python. Thanks. [image]

Comment: What software is this output from?

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find 
information on how to do this in the **My Account** 
section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.